# Storybook create a hidden story to be included in mdx docs

Tags: storybook

I'm creating documentation for a complex component in Storybook and would like to create a working example inside an mdx file. To do this my approach is usually to integrate a story into my mdx using the Story tag.
Is there a way to create a story to bo integrated into my mdx but without it being visible with the other stories in the sidebar?

I am using storybook 7 and my components are made with vue (although I think this is irrelevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution to this question, I ended up with the followind solution:

I have added a **display:none** rule to sidebar buttons (by their id) in the *manager-head.html* file in the *.storybook* folder.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this Storybook now supports a filter function for sidebar items to filter out stories you don't want to show that are still used in *.mdx documentation:

Create a manager.ts file with the following content in your .storybook folder:

```
import { addons } from '@storybook/manager-api';
import startCase from 'lodash/startCase.js';

addons.setConfig({
  sidebar: {
    filters: {
      a: (item) => item.depth === 2,
    },
  },
});
```

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/23722